# Relative Humidity inside a thermally insulated chamber for a NACL solution

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions, home-experiment

I ran an experiment, where I had to measure the relative humidity of a thermally insulated chamber containing NaCl solution. I have read from a few papers, that the relative humidity of a NaCl solution remains at 75% over a wide range of temperatures (20C to 30C).

But when I can change the temperature inside the chamber from 20C to 30C the relative humidity changes from 80% to 60%.

I am having trouble understanding what exactly is happening here. I thought it might be the pressure change caused by temperature change, so I created a small hole (needle width) to compensate for it but the result remains the same.

[image]

Comment: You have ignored the kinetics. Water vapor needs some time to reach higher level of absolute humidity at equilibrium. // The initial high relative humidity was not well balanced either, unless the sensor was improperly calibrated.

Comment: Could you cite your sources? E.g. https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/53/jresv53n1p19_A1b.pdf and https://www.teaforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=177. Also, how are you measuring relative humidity, and is your instrument calibrated just for room temperature or for the entire range?

Comment: @KarstenTheis I am using a calibrated SHT31 from Dracal which has both calibrated humidity and temperature. And here are my sources 1.) https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/53/jresv53n1p19_A1b.pdf 2.) https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/salt-humidity-d_1887.html 3.) https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/81A/jresv81An1p89_A1b.pdf

Comment: Nicely done experiment... now just run it 10 or 100 times slower, to allow it to reach equilibrium.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I try slowing down the process to see if it works. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Poutnik I try slowing the experiment. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Note that NaCl solution is supposed to be saturated with excess of the solid salt. Geometry is adviced to have maximized liquid surface and minimal depth. Be aware that it is slow process, especially at cooling down, as condensed water has to dissolve the solid salt to keep solution saturated.